# How to get WHOLE content of iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I need to get whole content of iframe from the same domain. Whole content means that I want everything starting from `<html>` (including), not only `<body>` content.
Content is modified after load, so I can't get it once again from server.

Comment: Are you trying to store all resources somewhere in the browser or what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to send modified content to server.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I belive I've found the best solution:

```
var document = iframeObject.contentDocument;
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var content = serializer.serializeToString(document);
```

In `content` we have full iframe content, including `DOCTYPE` element, which was missing in previous solutions. And in addition this code is very short and clean.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: This is totally wrong, you missed a semicolon :)
Thanks a lot.

Comment: One issue I have with this approach is that it encodes the iframe content. Everything gets Html encoded including font-family styles for example. If you have style tag with font-family defines as "Courier New", Courier, monospace then the double quotes will get encoded.

Answer (score 7):

If it is on the same domain, you can just use

```
iframe.contentWindow.document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

to get the content of the iframe, except for the `<html>` and `</html>` tag, where

```
iframe = document.getElementById('iframeid');
```

Comment: I also need `<html>` tag with all attributes.

Comment: You can loop through `iframe.contentWindow.document.documentElement`'s attribute to create the wrapping HTML tag (or use the non-standard `outerHTML`). A sample cross-browser code could be found here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljloliex.php.

Comment: The first solution is more less acceptable (can't use `outerHTML` because FF doesn't support it). It would be simplier if jQuery allowed me to wrap created `html` tag in another "wrapper" tag and the use `html()` method on that wrapper... Of course "Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy"

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input.test').click(function(){
    $('textarea.test').text($('iframe.test').contents());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the literal source of any file on the same domain with Ajax, which does not render the html first-

//

```
function fetchSource(url, callback){

    try{
        var O= new XMLHttpRequest;
        O.open("GET", url, true);
        O.onreadystatechange= function(){
            if(O.readyState== 4 && O.status== 200){
                callback(O.responseText);
            }
        };
        O.send(null);
    }
    catch(er){}
    return url;
}
function printSourceCode(text){
    var el= document.createElement('textarea');
    el.cols= '80';
    el.rows= '20';
    el.value= text;
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.focus();
}
```

**fetchSource(location.href, printSourceCode);**

Comment: "Content is modified after load, so I can't get it once again from server."