# How to get iframe content?

Tags: jquery

How to get content from an iframe with header `content-type: text/plan`?

Is it possible to load the content with `$.ajax()` without reloading the content?

iframe content:

```
{"result":{"posts":0,"posts_imported":0},"error":{"file":{"msg":"ERR_ERROR_FILE","trans":{"file":"csv"}}}}
```

Comment: Is the `iframe`'s content on the same domain as the page containing the `iframe`?

Comment: Do you mean a header of text/plain?

Comment: [.contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)?

Comment: `text/plain`? Looks like JSON to me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get WHOLE content of iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575219/how-to-get-whole-content-of-iframe)

Comment: thanks sime.. found the answer by following your link :)

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery :

```
var content = $("iframe").contents();
```

Answer (score -1):

How about:

your iframe html file:

a div

```
<div id='iframeContent'>
    {"result":{"posts":0,"posts_imported":0},"error":{"file":{"msg":"ERR_ERROR_FILE","trans":{"file":"csv"}}}}
</div>
```

then your code to replace it would be, I believe,

```
$('your-iframeid').childen('<div>',0).text(your-new-text);
```

I am a beginner; so, I might be completely off on this one (too).

Comment: Make sure to indent any code like HTML, javascript, etc. 4 spaces in - or use the Code toolbar button (looks like "{}").